# Weird dba|all_views text column content

Tags: oracle

I need to fetch underlying SELECT command for a view but can't find reliable way because data dictionary behaves weird for some (at least SYS) views.

Many of the views have NULL value in TEXT (LONG) column although the TEXT_LENGTH value is greater than 0.

What is weird is that if I add `WHERE text IS NULL` no row is returned so it seems that value is actually not null.

Oracle version is 12.1.0.2.

```
HUSQVIK@orcl> SET NULL (null)
HUSQVIK@orcl> SET LONG 32767
HUSQVIK@orcl> SELECT text_length, text FROM dba_views WHERE view_name = 'USER_TAB_COLS_V$';

TEXT_LENGTH TEXT
----------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       8051 (null)

1 row selected.

HUSQVIK@orcl> SELECT text_length, text FROM dba_views WHERE view_name = 'USER_TAB_COLS_V$' AND text IS NULL;

no rows selected

HUSQVIK@orcl>
```

I know I can use `dbms_utility.expand_sql_text` function (Oracle 12 only) but I don't want to expand views that use other views that use X$ tables as they are accessible only when logged as SYS.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about it doing weird things for SYS views unless you need to look at those, and it doesn't seem like you do. DBA_VIEWS is itself a view so odd effects from predicate pushing might explain why you get no rows in your second query. Do you still see issues if you exclude SYS-owned objects?

Comment: Hm, I think I can live with this. It seems that user views have always the LONG value if they are longer than 4k. It's really more just curiosity to expand system views. But in general I prefer approaches that work in all cases. Another interesting thing is that TEXT column can contain other view options like 'WITH READ ONLY' which makes the SELECT command invalid.

Comment: Do you see the same thing if you query the objects DBA_VIEWS looks at; `sys.view$` etc. - assuming you have access to those directly. Is using `dbms_metadata.get_ddl` an option, though you'd have to somehow remove everything up to the AS/IS?

Comment: Yes with DBA_VIEWS; actually view$ has only few rows (61 in my case, and all of them have TEXT with value) compared to the DBA|ALL_VIEWS

Comment: Just ran into the same problem, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61868170/how-can-i-get-the-complete-definition-sql-of-system-views-like-user-objects/61869547#61869547). I believe it has something to do with the containers in 12