# How can I get the complete definition (sql) of system views like user_objects?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, database-administration

I want to get the complete SQL code of the system views like USER_OBJECTS. However, when I execute the query below, it returns an error saying view not found in the SYS schema.

```
select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('VIEW', 'USER_OBJECTS', 'SYS') from dual;
```

When I execute the query below, it returns some codes in the text_vc column, but not the complete one. I cannot see the tables and where clause etc.

```
select * from ALL_VIEWS where VIEW_NAME  = 'USER_OBJECTS';
```

But with this query, I can see that it is in the SYS schema with that name.
So, what is the reason that I cannot see the whole query? And is there a way to see it all?

Comment: What is your Oracle version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

+1 for looking at the definitions of the system views!

The first problem (DBMS_METADATA empty) is a privilege problem. According to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_metada.htm#ARPLS66868), normal users will see only their own objects. You'll need the role `SELECT_CATALOG_ROLE` or `EXP_FULL_DATABASE` to see other users objects.

The second problem (SQL is not complete) comes from the datatype [LONG](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF00201), which - according to Oracle - should not be used anymore. However, it is still used by Oracle for view definitions, defaults, constraint text etc. Because it is so hard to handle, the view `ALL_VIEWS` has the original text in the `LONG` column and a truncated text, mostly the first 4000 characters, in the column `text_vc`, presumably for "text in varchar".

EDIT:

I believe you use Oracle 12 as you mention the column `text_vc`, which is not available in Oracle 11. Presumably, you are using a containerized database. If so, then please have a look at [Data Dictionary Architecture in a CDB](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/multi/overview-of-the-multitenant-architecture.html#GUID-A356382A-413A-4A42-98DC-6C2464808202). Apparently, the definition of Oracle supplied things like views and packages are only visible in the root container. Sigh!!

Answer (score 1):

In SQL*Plus, you'd `set long` (I shortened the output):

```
SQL> set pagesize 0
SQL> set long 10000
SQL>
SQL> select text from all_views where view_name = 'USER_OBJECTS';
select o.name, o.subname, o.obj#, o.dataobj#,
       decode(o.type#, 0, 'NEXT OBJECT', 1, 'INDEX', 2, 'TABLE', 3, 'CLUSTER',
                      4, 'VIEW', 5, 'SYNONYM', 6, 'SEQUENCE',
                      7, 'PROCEDURE', 8, 'FUNCTION', 9, 'PACKAGE',
                      11, 'PACKAGE BODY', 12, 'TRIGGER',
<snip>
from sys."_CURRENT_EDITION_OBJ" o
where o.owner# = userenv('SCHEMAID')
  and o.linkname is null
  and (o.type# not in (1  /* INDEX - handled below */,
                      10 /* NON-EXISTENT */)
       or
<snip>
union all
select l.name, NULL, to_number(null), to_number(null),
       'DATABASE LINK',
       l.ctime, to_date(null), NULL, 'VALID', 'N', 'N', 'N', NULL, NULL
from sys.link$ l
where l.owner# = userenv('SCHEMAID')


SQL>
```

---

Also, your first query works in my database (11g XE) **if** I'm connected as `SYS`:

```
SQL> show user
USER is "SYS"
SQL> select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('VIEW', 'USER_OBJECTS', 'SYS') from dual;

DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('VIEW','USER_OBJECTS','SYS')
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW "SYS"."USER_OBJECTS" ("OBJECT_NAME", "SUBOBJECT_N
AME", "OBJECT_ID", "DATA_OBJECT_ID", "OBJECT_TYPE", "CREATED", "LAST_DDL_TIME",
"TIMESTAMP", "STATUS", "TEMPORARY", "GENERATED", "SECONDARY", "NAMESPACE", "EDIT
ION_NAME") AS
  select o.name, o.subname, o.obj#, o.dataobj#,
       decode(o.type#, 0, 'NEXT OBJECT', 1, 'INDEX', 2, 'TABLE', 3, 'CLUSTER',
                      4, 'VIEW', 5, 'SYNONYM', 6, 'SEQUENCE',
                      7, 'PROCEDURE', 8, 'FUNCTION', 9, 'PACKAGE',
                      11, 'PACKAGE BODY', 12, 'TRIGGER',
<snip>
```

Comment: get_ddl works in 11, but not in 12.2, do you know why?

Comment: I don't have any 12.2 to try, @wolφi. I do have access to 12.2.0.1.0 and it works there.

Comment: am also on 12.2.0.1.0. Doc ID 2479803.1 says I've looked into the  wrong container. After `alter session set container=cdb$root;` everything works.